# IOS 9.3.5 breaks slow motion video playback - how to fix?

Tags: ios, iphone

I had hesitations about upgrading and just found out that my slow motion videos no longer play back. Displays a white spinner instead. I tried hard reset and recording a new video. No luck

**How to make slow motion videos play back on iOS 9.3.5 and iPhone 6s+?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are the videos recorded with camera.app or a third-party app? How long are the videos? Have you let it sit with the spinner for a minute or two to see if it eventually plays?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by recording a new regular video (60 fps) and playing it back. The video plays, and after that slow motion videos play as well. Until this step, slow motion videos displayed a spinner and did not play.